# Which type of errors captured on req.on(''error)

Tags: node.js

i am using node.js i write a small code

```
var http = require('http');


 var options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

i have to send post requests for starting i am making get requests that why no http.get().in this request i am getting 404 response code which is also an error.but not captured in req.on('error') .i want to know which kind of error this methd captures ??

Answer (score -1):

From [http.request documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback):

> If any error is encountered during the request (be that with DNS resolution, TCP level errors, or actual HTTP parse errors) an 'error' event is emitted on the returned request object.

So probably that event is only emitted when there is an error at the protocol/connection level.

You can then process HTTP errors on the `connect` call:

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  if (res.statusCode == "404"){ ... }
  else if (...) {
      ...
  } else { // everything ok
      console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
      console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
      ...
  }
});
```